# Jenkins Pipeline GitException Error

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Created a standard new jenkins pipeline job, tried to build job but got the following error:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not create directory '/var/jenkins_home/caches/git-ac8db26abc8a81bf2fcebfae6a8c6c98'
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:682)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.init(CliGitAPIImpl.java:215)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.init(GitAPI.java:217)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:279)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:196)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:172)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:246)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Finished: FAILURE
```

My Jenkinsfile is in github

Please does any one know why this is happening?

Comment: I would say you messed up your permissions.. check if the user running Jenkins has write permissions.

Comment: @StephenKing Thanks for the response. Yes this user has write permission. The weird thing is that other jobs that are not pipeline works but not pipeline jobs. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no clue then.

Comment: I have seen what they issue was. You are in a way right.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit, please? This might help others running into the same problem.

Comment: Yes did. Added in Answer section so it easily seen

Answer (score 0):

The `caches` folder on jenkins home have owner and group as `root:999` while other folders are `1000:1000`. Jenkins was build using docker and the container had been restarted multiple time (`jenkins_home` is on volume mount to reserve data). I guess I may have started it initially with `root:999` (not sure). Resolution:

`chown 1000:1000 cache`